# DIVs left and right over VIDEO

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to put a Video element between two DIVs.The DIVs should overlay the Video, so that parts of the Video are not visible to the customer. My english is not the best, so I made a small image :)
It should look like this:

```
+       full video width                   +
+------------------------------------------+

+------------+-----------------+-----------+
|            |                 |           |
|            |                 |           |
|            |                 |           |
|            |                 |           |
|  Overlay1  |  Visible part   |  Overlay2 |
|            |  of video       |           |
|            |                 |           |
|            |                 |           |
|            |                 |           |
|            |                 |           |
|            |                 |           |
|            |                 |           |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

My HTML and CSS Code Looks like this:

```css
#videoElement {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 720px;
}

.video-overlay1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 720px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.video-overlay2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1000px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 720px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-overlay1">
  <div class="video-overlay2">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way you can do this is to have the following:

Have a container DIV which acts as the parent div and will hold the video at width 100%.

Inside the div container (parent) have overlay 1 div floated left at a desired width and overlay div 2 floated right at a desired width.

Please read up on floating here if needed https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: That led me to the answer. Thank you @Stan-Howe